# Multirow inside tabular column declaration

Tags: tables, multirow

Is it possible to use `\multirow` command inside the column declaration of the `tabular` environment (provided by [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package)?

I want to obtain the following result:

[image: desired result]

Which I can achieve by doing that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{%
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}% 1st column
        m{2.5cm}% 2nd column
    }
    \toprule
    text & \multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{\centering$a+b$} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \midrule
    text & \multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{\centering$x+y$} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, I tried to clean things up a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{%
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}%
        >{\multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{\centering\arraybackslash\(}m{2.5cm}<{\)\}}% <--- added '\multirow' here
    }
    \toprule
    text & a+b \\      % <--- Removed '\multirow' from here
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \midrule
    text & x+y \\      % <--- Removed '\multirow' from here
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This second approach obviously won't work, since neither `<{\)\}}` nor `<{\)}}` works.

I guess `\}` should print the brace, while `}` just closes everything as `<{\)}` and leaves another `}` remaining.

So, is it possible to close this brace somehow? That is, to make `>{\multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{\centering\arraybackslash\(}m{2.5cm}<{\)}}` works.

---

##### Note:

I'm aware of the possibility of declaring a command such as

```
\newcommand{\MR}[1]{\multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{\centering\ensuremath{#1}}}
```

to use like `\MR{a+b}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Life is easier if you use my new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) to make multirow or multicolumn cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[c,m,3cm]m{2.5cm}}, 
  cell{odd}{2} = {r=2}{c}, % multirow
}
  \toprule
    text & $a+b$ \\
  \cmidrule[r]{1-1}
    text &       \\
  \midrule
    text & $x+y$ \\
  \cmidrule[r]{1-1}
    text &       \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Updated**: From version `2021N`, `tabularray` supports trim options `l`, `r` and `lr`, but you need to put them inside *square brackets*.

Comment: +1. In this particular case the advantage of tblr comes especially to the fore.

Comment: Definitely a cleaner code! Is it possible to use that with `longtable`? **Nota:** Eu uso o [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) e por algum motivo ele reclama sobre não encontrar o `tabularray.sty`. Eu precisei colocar esse arquivo manualmente nele para que tudo funcionasse, você sabe algo sobre isso?

Comment: Yes, there is a `longtblr` environment. Please read the manual.

Comment: I can not read your words in other language. I can only guess: `tabularray` is a new package and not in `overleaf` yet. You can download `tabularray.sty` and `ninecolors.sty` from CTAN and upload them to your TeX project folder in `overleaf`.

Comment: OMG, I sincerely apologize!! I was thinking in Portuguese and didn't noticed, my fault. Yes, you guessed it right, thank you! **Note:** I use [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) and for some reason it complains about not finding `tabularray.sty`. I had to manually put this file into it for everything to work, do you know anything about that?

Comment: @Leone With version 2021N of `tabularray`, trim options `l`, `r` and `lr` are supported. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify your first MWE is to use `\multirowsetup` and change its default settings as follows:

```
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
```

Using it, your first MWE become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow}

\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{%
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}% 1st column
        m{2.5cm}% 2nd column
    }
    \toprule
    text & \multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{$a+b$} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \midrule
    text & \multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{$x+y$} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and compilation result of it is:

[image]

**Edit:**
If you like to make some shortcut for this particular multirow cell, you can define it as:

```
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\newcommand{\MR}[1]{\multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{$#1$}}
```

And than this MWE write as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow}

\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\newcommand{\MR}[1]{\multirow{2}{=}[-2.5pt]{$#1$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{%
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}% 1st column
        m{2.5cm}% 2nd column
    }
    \toprule
    text & \MR{a+b} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \midrule
    text & \MR{x+y} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    text &  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: I was about to say that `\multirowsetup` was kind of already covered by declaring a new command (see my note in the question) and you included it in your answer :D. Well, I will let this question opened for a while, but probably `\newcommand` is the best way out.

Comment: @Leone, to my opinion, it is not :-(. It hasn't any flexibility. For example, what you will do, if multirow should span more than two text lines? Or of the distance around horizontal lines is different as in its definition is anticipated? etc ... well, if your definition for `MR` solve your problem, what is the question?

Comment: Now I would say that my question is a matter of curiosity. I would like to know about the possibility of doing something like my second approach (to open and close commands in column declaration). The truth is: I simplified my problem. While I was implementing a MWE to post this question here, I didn't realized that the lack of flexibility would be a problem to me. At first I "solved" my problem by declaring `MR`, then I came up with the idea of setting the column up at the column declaration field (to avoid having to put `MR` in every cell). >>>

Comment: >>> Only after that I faced one problem that you listed: the number of lines in which multirow spans. So... my second approach, even if it somehow work, will never fit my current needs (I will have to declare a `MR` command with some options, no problem), but if it did, would it be possible to do?